# How to unmarshal dynamic YAML to a map of string -> string -> struct in Go?

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal the YAML data found below in this code. What is wrong with my struct definition? How should it be to match the data format?

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WXj_bxnARcZ)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
fruits:
  apple:
    comments:
    - good
    - sweet
    from: US 
  pear:
    comments:
    - nice
    from: Canada
veggies:
  potato:
    comments:
    - filling
    from: UK
`

type List struct {
    Category map[string]struct {
        Name map[string]struct {
            Comments []string `yaml:"comments"`
            From     string   `yaml:"from"`
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var l List
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &l)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(l)
}
```

The code above outputs an empty map `{map[]}`.

Solution:

Fixed playground as per the verified answer [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ejCGeTp9ubB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two problems:

First, your `List` type does not match your data. It expects something of the form:

```yaml
---
Category:
  XXX:
    Name:
       XXX:
           Comments: [ ... ]
           From: ...
```

Where 'XXX' are arbitrary keys.  This is obviously not what you have.

It looks like you just want a map:

```golang
type List map[string]map[string]struct{
    Comments []string
    From     string
}
```

Second, you must pass a pointer to your destination object to the `Unmarshal` function:

```golang
    var l List
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &l) // <-- note &l not l
```

Comment: Thank you! Both for the assistance in getting to the right stage, and in this clear explanation!